# Ajax Request in Node - Avoid Page Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have an ajax request being called on form submit. The idea is to save a user's account information without a page reload, and give them a handy flash message to let them know the save was successful. I have no problem saving the data, but I *do* have a problem with avoiding a redirect on the POST (to a white page with the response data). Here's what I have:

**In my Jade view**

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
        $ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/account', 
            data: $("#accountForm").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                // can req.flash even be used here? How might it be?
                req.flash('info', {msg: 'Your profile has been updated!'});
            }
        }
}
```

**In my controller**

```
exports.postAccount = function(req, res, next) {

    var userData = req.body;
    userData.id = req.user.user_id;

    var updateUserCallback = function(err) {
         // This is where everything falls apart
         // Theoretically this should run the success handler in the ajax response
         res.json(true);
         // Any response I send changes the view to a white page with the data, e.g.
         // res.send(anyData);
         // Flash also doesn't seem to work, which seems weird...
         req.flash('info', {msg: 'Your profile has been updated!'});
    }
    // Successfully saves the data, no problems here
    UserModel.updateUser(userData, updateUserCallback);
};
```

Normally in the updateUserCallback I would just *render the account view*, but that defeats the purpose of ajax. I want to save the user's data without a page reload/redirect, while letting them know that the ajax function completed successfully (or didn't) via `req.flash` (flash module).

Basically any `res.send()` or `res.json()` call puts that data into a plain white page (no view). I suppose that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how ajax works, but I've followed other examples for jQuery ajax calls in Node and have not been able to avoid the 'white page' problem.

Answer (score 1):

Node:

```
var updateUserCallback = function(err) {
     return res.send({
         message: "Your profile has been updated"
     });
}
```

Client-side JS:

```
success: function(response) {
     // can req.flash even be used here? How might it be?
     // Nope
     //req.flash('info', {msg: 'Your profile has been updated!'});
     $('#someModal').show().html(response.message); // just a sample implementation
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to run the query (update) and *not* `res.send()` anything back? I' like to just `req.flash()` in the callback, and send a success notification to the jquery function (for disabling the 'save' button once the call is finished). If I have access to the `res` object in the callback, I should have access to `req` as well. But in order for the response to end (no infinite loop when the ajax is called) then I need to call `res.end()` eventually (through `res.send()`, `res.json()`, etc. But even if I just add `res.end()` to the callback, I still get a white page (view change) =/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the form submit, you can use simple button click so that page will not get reloaded.